# Django errors on Python with Subterfuge

Tags: python, django, linux, pythonpath, archlinux

I just installed a new MiTM software called: [Subterfuge](http://code.google.com/p/subterfuge)
on Arch Linux 32-bit but when I try to run it as sudo I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/subterfuge/manage.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_manager
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

I am posting here because I believe that this is a general error related to Python paths, 
however I don't know how to work around it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the module 'django.core.management' is not installed... 
Have add it in the INSTALLED_APP in settings.py?

Comment: I don't think so...how do I do that?

Comment: `django.core` packages don't have to be added to `INSTALLED_APPS`. Looks more like django isn't in PYTHONPATH (or not installed at all). To verify try `import django` from the Python interactive shell.

Answer (score 1):

Allright.
Problem solved.

User 'Steve K' provided the solution in this thread:
[django import error - No module named core.management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049933/django-import-error-no-module-named-core-management)

I 'vimed' the very first line of this file:
`/usr/share/subterfuge/manage.py`

and changed the following line:
`#!/usr/bin/env python`

to

`#!/usr/bin/env python2`

Apparently python pointed to python 3 on my system and that's why the file couldn't be processed.

Comment: Arch Linux uses Python 3 as standard already. They fix all the magic lines of Python software with sed in their packages.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that django is already installed ?

Django is still experimental on python 3

try a:
  python -c 'import django'

Experimental Python 3 support

by Aymeric Augustin on Aug. 19, 2012

The Django project reached a significant milestone today: for the first time, the development version of Django passes the test suite under Python 3.2, with the SQLite and PostgreSQL backends.

The community is encouraged to test this pre-alpha version and report bugs under Python 3 as well as regressions under Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

Install python-pip first.

> apt-get install python-pip

Then run the subterfuge setup.py

> python setup.py

It will install Django along with it. But you can install Django manually by

> pip install django=="1.7"

**Note:** Currently it supports django 1.7