# Django PATH and running manage.py

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am trying to run manage.py and i keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

I have tried setting my path to `"/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/"` and also added the path `"/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django"` just in case, but neither to seem to be working.

I have checked the module, and it exits, so this has to be a PATH issue.  Can anyone help?

I am running Python 2.7.4 and Django 1.5.2

Thank you

Comment: What does `sys.path` returns?

Comment: [Some ideas in this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049933/django-import-error-no-module-named-core-management)

Comment: Where did you set this path?  And are you running in a virtualenv?

Comment: can you import django from the terminal ? you can also check your sys.path from the terminal...

Comment: I'm not using virtualenv currently, but plan to add it.  So, my python must have been python3 on bluehost.com, my hosting site, because when i typed "python2 manage.py" it worked.  Then i did "alias python=python2.7" and then ran as normal "python manage.py" and that worked too, so I guess that was the issue.  Thank you everyone, and @karthikr that other thread had good info and those are the solutions that i tried n worked. thanks