# error in python virtual environment

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I am trying to run a project that was setup in another server, but getting the following error. I am using python 2.7, django, virtualenv. So I am running the project inside a python virtual environment

```
(virtualenv)[web.srv1 daily# python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

Traceback (most recent call last):    
  File "manage.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_manager    
ImportError: cannot import name execute_manager
```

I used the method mentioned in the below link to setup the virtual environment.

http://toic.org/blog/2011/wsgi-on-cpanel-improved/

This project was setup inside a cpanel server. But the current server I using is not a cpanel server. It is normal centos server.

Can somebody help me to track down the issue.

Comment: what's django version?

Comment: this function deprecated from version 1.4 and removed in 1.6
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#django-core-management-execute-manager

Comment: possible duplicate of [django import error - No module named core.management](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049933/django-import-error-no-module-named-core-management)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because you're using a project that used a different version of django from the one you have in your `virtualenv`.

This problem has arisen in the past, and *has* been answered on stackoverflow. The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049933/django-import-error-no-module-named-core-management).

Comment: Thank you for the help. That fixed the issue. But I have another issue arising.

    ImportError: No module named setuptools.command
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>

ImportError: No module named setuptools.command

I did install setuptools. I followed the below link
 

http://toic.org/blog/2011/wsgi-on-cpanel-improved/

Comment: Thats a separate question, so feel free to ask it as a separate one.

Comment: That also got fixed. I used
# pip install --upgrade setuptools

Comment: @user3050288 You can do that by pressing the tickmark to the left hand side of the answer.