# Import error cannot import name execute_manager in windows environment

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I'll get you up to speed. I'm trying to setup a windows dev environment. I've successfully installed python, django, and virtualenv + virtualenwrapper([windows-cmd installer](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html))

```
workon env
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:24) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION
(1,6,1, 'final',0)
>>> quit()
```

But when I run: `python manage.py runserver` from my cloned repository I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)"
File "manage.py", line 2, in (module)
from django.core.management import execute_manager
ImportError: cannot import name execute_manager
```

Both python and django are added to my system variable PATH:

```
...C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts\;C:\PYTHON27\DLLs\;C:\PYTHON27\LIB\;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\;
```

I've also tried this with bash and powershell and I still get the same error.

Is this a virtualenv related issue? Django dependence issue? Yikes. How do I fix this problem? Help me Stackoverflow-kenobi your my only hope.

Comment: Are you actually using virtualenv? The whole point of it is *not* to use the system-wide python interpreter along with its libraries. Check the accepted answer for the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049933/django-import-error-no-module-named-core-management It touches on virtualenv setup.

Comment: @matcheek Hmm it looks like I'm not properly running the virtualenv. After running the proper django version, I get this error: ImportError: No module named djcelery.

Comment: @matcheek I checked if django would run in python outside of my environment and it does. Also the link you suggested is for a linux environment.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

`execute_manager` deprecated in Django 1.4 as part of the project layout refactor and was removed in 1.6 per the deprecation timeline: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/internals/deprecation/#id3

To fix this error you should either install a compatible version of Django for the project or update the `manage.py` to new style which does not use `execute_manager`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/releases/1.4/#updated-default-project-layout-and-manage-py Most likely if your `manage.py` is not compatible with 1.6 then neither is the rest of the project. You should find the appropriate Django version for the project.

Comment: Thank you for your timely reply. It looks like that helped. I'm successfully running 1.3.1 (version my project requires). However it looks like it may have been a virtualenv problem. Because I'm getting this error: ImportError: No module named djcelery.

Comment: That error seems pretty clear. You haven't installed `django-celery`.

Answer (score 5):

@Mark Lavin explained nicely what the error means and how it arises.  I think I've just discovered why others may also get this error message so leaving it here for the record.

I'm assuming you're running this from within a virtual environment.

When starting a new Django project, if you run `django-admin startproject <myproject>`, you are invoking the global installation of Django.  If, as in my case, it comes from a stale repo, it may be an old version - in my case:

```
>> django-admin --version
>> 1.3.1
```

If you want to run Django from within a virtual environment, then you need to invoke it with `django-admin.py startproject <myproject>`.  This way, you get a Django project with the version corresponding to your *local* installation:

```
>> django-admin.py --version
>> 1.6.6
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error because I had an old version of `django-admin.py` in my `/usr/local/bin` folder and I had forgotten to create a new virtualenv for my new project.

Remember that the steps for a new project should be:

1. First create a new virtualenv for your new project:
   `mkvirtualenv <mynewproj>`
2. Update the Python version for your virtualenv if necessary:
   `virtualenv --python $(which python3.6) ~/.virtualenvs/<mynewproj>`
3. Then create your Django project folder structure:
   `django-admin startproject <django project name>`

I also deleted my old obsolete `/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py` because it was created before I discovered the joys of `virtualenv`.