# Running django in virtualenv - ImportError: No module named django.core.management?

Tags: django, virtualenv

I have installed Django after activating my virtualenv but still I am getting following error

```
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049933/django-import-error-no-module-named-core-management?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you already activated your virtualenv (`source /path/bin/activate`) then check if you have installed Django.

```
pip install django
```

With next command you can see if Django was installed.

```
pip freeze | grep django
```

Another thing that you can try is to remove first line (`#!/usr/bin/env python`) in the `manage.py` file.

Comment: yes its fixed, it was happening because i was using `sudo pip install django`, it always says satisfied if the django is already installed.

Comment: OH MY CRAP!  I hadnt finished building this virtenv.  THANK YOU!

Comment: Yep, this is almost always the case. Simple problem, but easy to overlook.

Answer (score 6):

You should check if django is installed
Activate your environment, then run the following command to see which version is installed :

```
python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using virtual environment so I added this line in `manage.py`:

```
sys.path.append('./myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages')
```

in which `myvenv` is the name of my virtual environment and version of my installed Python is `3.5`. 
This solved my issued.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had Python 3.4 and 2.7 installed concurrently, and the `pip install django==1.7` command automagically decided the Python 3.4 /dist-packages was where it should live.  I CD'd over to the Python 2.7 directory and re-piped it... and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

```
 sudo pip install django --upgrade
```

worked for me, i am not having virutal environment by the way.

Comment: This is a very offensive comment. It's stackoverflow not youtube or facebook. Virtualenvs help you avoid many problems that you are going face when you will have many different kind of python projects. Start good practice from day one.

Comment: if you have virtual environment this alone would not solve your problem

Comment: Bad answer as you are defeating the purpose of virtualenv and installing django systemwide.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I was running Django from inside a virtual environment and then using another terminal window ran the command 
`python manage.py shell` without first switching to the venv.

The problem was resolved after I switched back.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I could import the django module from the python interpreter, but django-admin.py could not import it when run from the command line.

I confirmed that I was using the python interpreter in my virtual environment.

I was using a 64-bit version of python. Uninstalling, and installing the 32-bit version, then re-creating my venv solved this for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using virtualenv, you can add it to your path using `sys.path.append('./myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages')`.

Try closing and opening the terminal again. That worked for me too.