# Getting error on running manage.py runserver

Tags: python, django, django-1.8, django-manage.py, manage.py

I am new to Django, I got an error on executing manage.py even though having installed Django.

Here is the error message:

```
vivekmehra88@vivekmehra88-HP-Pavilion-TS-15-Notebook-PC:~/PycharmProjects/myProj/django-apps/testsite$ python3 manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named 'django'
vivekmehra88@vivekmehra88-HP-Pavilion-TS-15-Notebook-PC:~/PycharmProjects/myProj/django-apps/testsite$ django-admin --version 
1.8.7
```

Comment: Have you activated environment(where you installed django) while execution manage.py ??

Comment: are you using a virtualenv ?? is yes, make sure you call the pyton interepreter located there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django import error - No module named core.management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049933/django-import-error-no-module-named-core-management)

Answer (score 0):

Run `pip freeze` and see if you have django installed.

If you are using a virtual environment then start that with `source venv/bin/activate` or whatever you've named it. In this case I named it venv.  Then run pip freeze.  You should probably `run pip freeze >> requirements.txt` to produce a requirements.txt file.

This will make it easier to rebuild the app in the cloud or on a different computer or just in a new virtual environment by calling `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to install required libraries to the run time environment. Since you haven't activated any virtual environment you are using root python libraries. `sudo pip3 freeze` will list down installed libraries.

if django isn't the list install django from `sudo pip3 install django` command.

Since django-admin run as a standalone application you get the version likewise.